# How to compare rows of two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, spotfire

I have 2 dataframes(df and df_flagMax) that are not the same in size. I need help on the structure of comparing two different databases that are not the same in size. I want to compare the rows of both dataframes.

```
df = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx')
df_flagMax = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['Max'].max()
df['flagMax'] = 0
num = len(df) 
for i in range(num):
    colMax = df.at[i, 'Name']
    df['flagMax'][(df['Max'] == colMax)] = 1 
    print(df)
```

df_flagMax data:

```
       Name       Max
 0     Sf       39.91
 1     Th      -25.74
```

**df data:**

[image: df_data]

For example: I want to compare 'Sf' from both df and df_flagMax and then perform this line:

```
 df['flag'][(df['Max'] == colMax)] = 1
```

if and only if the 'Sf' is in both dataframes on the same row index. The same goes for the next Name value ... 'Th'

Comment: It's a little hard to understand this question. Could you add some sample data that displays your actual data

Comment: It's not very clear. Add an example of data. As first guess I would append the two dataframes df_tot = df.append(df_flagMax) than use flag = df_tot.duplicated(keep=False) Now use this to flag duplicated in your df.

Comment: I added the two dataframes for reference